# Should it be an "unlike" or "dislike" button on Facebook?

Tags: meaning, neologisms, internet, social-media

I see an increasing demand for an *unlike* button on Facebook:

- http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Unlike-Button/72641866357
- [Facebook Adds An Unlike Button For Pages](http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-adds-unlike-2010-05)
  <sup>May 7, 2010</sup>
- [Facebook "Unlike" Button Comes to the News Feed](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/facebook_unlike_button_comes_to_the_news_feed.php)
  <sup>NOV 3, 2010</sup>

I have always used and understood *unlike* in the sense of dissimilar. Is it ever used in the sense of *do not like*?

Comment: Dunno'.  But it should probably be 'Facebook' (capital 'F', with 'b') in your title, rather than 'faceook'.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. Time for me to get a new keyboard, maybe? :)

Comment: "Time for .. new keyboard".  Maybe. :-)  Good luck with your question.  I won't contribute an answer since I am no expert on English, I just use it (poorly).

Comment: There _has_ been a lot of (ineffective) clamoring for a button that means 'dislike', in the sense of 'I don't like this' or 'I agree this is bad'. I think this is different, though, from undoing the action of 'liking' something, and that's what the 'unlike' action seems to be about.

Comment: Ultimately this is new ground, since "like" has never been a verb for an instantaneous action (whose effects can be reversed by a different action) before Facebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Unlike" in this case refers to the fact that you have "liked" this post, and now, due to a change of opinion, you decide to reverse that "like", by "un-liking" the post.

"Dislike" is not used here because "dislike" does not have the same effect that "unlike" has. "Unlike" is used in this case only to remove a "like", but "dislike" has the effect of not only removing the "like" but to actually have feelings of antipathy towards the post.

Putting it in SE style:

You see a post you believe is good, so you give a +1(like). After a while, you change opinions, so you remove your vote(unlike). Then, you think, this post is really bad, so you give it a -1(dislike)

Comment: so it should be un-like?

Comment: Yeah. "Unlike" means differently from "dislike", so "unlike" is more appropriate in this case.:-)

Comment: @rest_day: "..should be un-like?" I agree it should be 'un-like' (with '-') to make the distinction to 'unlike'<->'dissimilar'.  But I doubt we'll get our way.  BTW (musing) does 'undissimilar' mean the same/alike? ;)

Comment: No...won't the un- cancel out the dis-?

Answer (score 10):

In the modern world, and particularly in the world of computers, the **un-** prefix is increasingly used to denote an *opposite* or *reversing* action.

As in *install/uninstall*, *register/unregister*, and *delete/undelete*. Not to mention the *undo* facility we rely on in many applications.

In short, people quite reasonably expect the Facebook functionality to be called **unlike** because that follows the pattern they're used to. There's no danger of confusing such terminology with the *dissimilar* meaning, so why not?

Answer (score 2):

*Unlike* and *dislike* are both existing words in English, and neither of them has the correct meaning. You could call it *delike*. The prefix *de-* also means undo (for example *decontaminate*), although in association with computer actions it's not used as much as either *un-* or *dis-*.

Comment: I think one of the reasons we can get away with *unlike*, and save coining a new word, is the very fact that **un-** is such a common 'negating' prefix. I'm a fan of neologisms when they help crystalise / popularise subtle concepts. But not just to avoid overloading existing words with additional easily-understood meanings where ambiguity isn't an issue.