# How productive is the verb prefix "un-"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, negation, prefixes, productive-affixes

Is it possible to use *un-* with new words such as *sit, sleep, sad*? I'm currently seeing many words (in programming) which use *un-* in the meaning of undoing something.

For example, is it possible to use "make me unsleep" (the Chrome spell-checker underlines it) as a synonym for "wake me up"?

If yes, why is it so rare? And if not, why can't it be used?

Comment: The un- prefix doesn't make sense on all verbs, and even on verbs where it *might* make sense, it just isn't used (especially when a more common way to say the same thing exists).  I don't think there are any fixed rules about which verbs can take "un" and which ones can't.

Comment: I disagree: I have voted for reopening, and upvoted the question. At one level the question can be answered "Look in a dictionary"; but _un-_ is a partially productive prefix in English, and the range of verbs to which it may be added has recently expanded from what Whorf calls the _cryptotype_ of verbs of enclosing and fastening to a broader group, such as _select_ and _friend_. It would not surprise me to discover that some user-interface people talked about _unsleep_ for resuming a dormant process, for example.

Comment: @Colin Fine: *The Oxford Handbook of Cognitive Linguistics - Page 658* - [...gaps in the productivity of prefixation... can be observed with verbs that do not permit 'contrast' (*unlive, *unsit, *unsleep, *unplay)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J5IJscoeq_0C&pg=PA658&dq=%22unlive+unsit+unsleep+unplay%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c0mRUIrtGunL0QXuhYDoDA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22unlive%20unsit%20unsleep%20unplay%22&f=false)

Comment: @ColinFine  Your conjecture is [fact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751982(v=vs.85).aspx). But I think this is still a localized nonce-usage. And in any case, it does not address OP's question, which is not about 'unsleep' as a possible word but about actual use of 'make me unsleep' as a synonym for 'wake me up'.

Comment: @StoneyB: That is the OP's first question. I'm looking at the third one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Does a source that you can't read count as general reference? ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thanks, I didn't know about that theory. But it's not complete for this purpose: it doesn't exclude _unwrite_ or _unbreak_, for example.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I haven't voted on the Q at all yet, but following the edit I will vote to re-open. Actually, I'm a bit surprised you say *un- is a [only a] **partially** productive prefix*, since it seems to me it's unexceptional when creating "nonce-words". I can't make up my mind whether to call **unsay**, for example, a frequently-recoined nonce-word, or an archaism (it's attested in OED since 1460).

Comment: What's potentially interesting is that things can be *unsaid, unplayed, unlived* but it's not easy to *unsay* something. The *un-* prefix doesn't mean *de-*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Yes, but you occasionally hear people saying "I wish I could unsay that." In the adjectives, of course, *un-* signifies simply *not*, rather than *undo*.

Comment: sounds like progression to [newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak)

Comment: @Andrew Leach: That's because when it precedes an "adjectival" past participle verb form, the ***un-*** prefix can usually be unambiguously interpreted as meaning *never having been [verb-ed]*. But who can say what the negative/opposite of *say, play, live* etc. would mean in the more general context of those verbs?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty **un**-productive ;)

Comment: How about *undie*?  I'm not wearing undies right now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally *un-* with a verb means to reverse—“undo”—the previously-taken action of the verb. You “unscrew” a jar lid someone previously screwed on; you “unwrap” a package someone previously wrapped.

You can even use *un-* with verbs signifying actions normally regarded as irreversible—*create* or *kill*, for instance—as long as you are speaking or writing in a context where those verbs have non-literal meaning, such as game design.

But it is semantically awkward to use *un-* with *activities* or *statives* — verbs which signify  actions without particular goal or existence in a particular state.

“Sleep” is normally a stative, so it can’t be reversed. *Unsleep* would be acceptable only in cases where *sleep* was being used transitively, with the sense “put to sleep”, or inchoatively, with the sense “fall asleep” —neither of which is in my experience used.

Programmers, of course, *can* name variables or methods with any words in any sense they like. They are “communicating” only with compilers, which aren’t encumbered with the linguistic rules which obtain in natural languages.

And of course *you* can coin *unsleep* and use it in any sense *you* like. That’s how the language grows. But if you use such nonce-words in an unconventional way you will run the risk of mis- or non-understanding.

---

EDIT:
Since you ask about *sad*: You have considerably more leeway in prefixing *un-* to adjectives, including adjectives formed from participles, because here *un-* bears more general negative senses. *Unsleeping*, for instance, is perfectly conventional: an ‘unsleeping’ watchman is one who is not sleeping, not one who ‘unsleeps’ someone else. An ‘unlicked cub’ is a cub which has not been licked, not one which has been ‘unlicked’. *Un-* can also be prefixed to nouns with a simple negative sense—*unperson*, for instance. Verbs can even be formed by prefixing a noun with *un-* in the sense of ‘deprive of’ (*unstate*) or ‘remove from’ (*unearth*).

Comment: The distinction is crucial._Un_- is widely productive with adjectives, but much more limited with verbs.

Comment: Interestingly, the verb and adjective prefix *un-* apparently have different etymological origins: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/321631/77227

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.clt.gu.se/seminar/2011-05-19/clt-seminar-larry-horn) looks like what you're asking about.

As you can see, it's a topic of great interest to linguists, and [Larry Horn](http://ling.yale.edu/laurence-horn-personal-page) is pretty much **the** expert on [negation](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf).

To quote the abstract:

> Since Whorf (1936), many linguists have tried their hand at corralling the restrictions on the formation of "reversative" un-verbs; cf. e.g. Marchand (1969), Dowty (1979), Horn (1988), Clark et al. (1995). Why can you *unwrap* a sandwich but not *unrecognize* its contents or *unremember* to toss it in the trash? Why can a snake *uncoil* while a painting can't *unhang*?  If *unfreeze* is the opposite of *freeze*, why is *unthaw* a synonym of *thaw*?
>
> The standard approach to the constraints on un-verb formation invokes Whorf's CRYPTOTYPE -- a covert category encompassing transitive verbs of covering and enclosing that rules out a wide range of possible bases and outputs of the relevant rule. Pullum (1999), for example, reckons that there are "about a dozen verbs" that allow un-prefixation, citing *undo* (a good deed) and *unknow* as examples of formations we know "intuitively" are impossible. Clark et al. (1995) exclude *unbury* and *unbend*, while Kemmerer & Wright (2002) rule out *unboil* and *undecorate*. Yet many of the verbs depicted in the literature as impossible, non-occurring, or -- as in Whorf's label for *unsay* and *unmake* -- "semi-archaic" are readily attested, even when the actions they denote may be physically irreversible.
>
> While the Pullum/Whorf view may be extended to predict the pleonastic interpretation of source-oriented reversatives in Swedish, French, and English (*unloosen, unthaw*), it incorrectly limits the productivity of un-verb formation by conflating the SEMANTIC (aspectual) restrictions with the PRAGMATIC conditions on the way the world (normally) works; verbs like *unsay, unknow, unboil,* and *unhappen* are motivated precisely by the need to describe those (typically counterfactual) situations in which the tape of reality is reversed.
>
> The pragmatic nature of the restrictions on un-verb formation is supported by a survey of contexts that favor the emergence of innovative un-verbs: advances in science and technology (as in the *unerase* and *undelete* commands, the *unfriend* or *unlike* verbs of social networking, or the *unfuck* program to reverse software protection), science fiction (as in time-travel scenarios), advertising copy (as in KFC's current *unthink* campaign), and the imagination of poets from Shakespeare (whose "*un-king’d*" Richard II is the unchallenged monarch of this realm) to pop songsters (*"How can I unlove you?*", *"Un-break my heart*"), whether the implausibility of a given reversal is conceded, mourned, or overridden.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, un-, when attached to certain verbs, reverses the action expressed in it, as in uncover, undo, undress, unfasten, unleash, unload, unlock, unplug, untie, unwind, and go and go on. But many other verbs, like - for example - break, expect, seek, smile, cannot be reversed in this way. Sleep belongs to this last category, so you cannot say 'unsleep' for saying "wake me up".

Comment: I would agree, using _un-_ too loosely can create some very unfamiliar words; e.g., I wouldn't say that this emoticon is "unsmiling" :^(  This doesn't mean people couldn't figure out what you were trying to convey, but you might sound very uneducated while saying it.

Comment: But _unsmiling_ is a perfectly good and common word, as _smiling_ is an adjectival form. You're meaning it in a different sense, as though derived from a verb _unsmile_, I realise.

Answer (score 0):

Per my answer to [Should it be *unlike* or *dislike* button in Facebook?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/30335/2637), and noting OP's mention of programming, *install/uninstall, register/unregister, delete/undelete, do/undo* are now common in that context. And programmers wouldn't bat an eyelid at references to an [**unsleep** function](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2eBQFsoRU7sC&pg=PA229&dq=unsleep%20function&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3lORUP_IAcnS0QX2iYCgDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=unsleep%20function&f=false).

As that first link explains, there wasn't really any need for *unlike* before Facebook, because we already had *dislike*. But that didn't quite fit the Facebook context, so the new coinage succeeded.

Historically speaking, as [this answer to a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2542/2637) points out, *in general, words take un- when they are of English (Germanic) origin*. But it seems to me native speakers do tend to go for ***un-*** rather than other [negating prefixes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/are-there-any-patterns-to-observe-in-choosing-the-correct-negation-prefix-to-use) such as ***a-, an- in-, de- dis, dys,*** etc. when coining unashamedly facetious nonce-words, regardless of the base word's etymology.

I don't actually think ***un-*** is at all "rare" as a negating prefix for "standard" words. The reason it "can't" be used with ***unagree, unsit, unwatch*** etc., is mainly that these are not currently considered valid words (we already have the word ***disagree***, and ***unsit*** could only mean ***stand***, but I wouldn't be surprised to see ***unwatch*** appear in an eBay context soon).

As [these few instances show](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22unlive%20unsit%20unsleep%20unplay%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22of%20unsleep%22&oq=%22of%20unsleep%22&gs_l=serp.3...13093.13732.3.14093.5.5.0.0.0.0.72.275.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.2GddgJEz4M4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1301a46b09d10054&bpcl=36601534&biw=1302&bih=870), *unsleep* is "recoined" from time to time (often in literary/poetic contexts) but we're dealing with highly idiomatic usages here, and I would certainly advise non-native speakers to avoid forms they don't see others using frequently.

TL;DR: ***un-*** is not rare, but "acceptable" new coinages in established contexts are ***uncommon*** (few would be happy with [unrare](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JGEAHLg1rmcC&pg=PA69&dq=%22unrare%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=il6RUJ78GO_N0AXOjYC4BA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22unrare%22&f=false) there, for example).

Comment: I am afraid the largely ununiversitied English-speaking world is ununitable in its ununiform ununderstanding of  all matters unnish.

Comment: @tchrist: Haha - I just checked OED, which lists over a dozen **unun...** words. Including (ununsuprisingly?!) all of yours, which I take it you knew anyway.

Comment: "Unwatch" is already used in the context of wikis like Wikipedia, where logged in users can "watch" articles for changes.

Comment: Again, you're not distinguishing between verbs and adjectives.

Comment: @Colin Fine: That's true, and I did accept the point in relation to comments against StoneyB's answer. If OP had specifically asked about the scope for "negating" **verbs** using "un-", I think I'd just delete this answer. But he asked a more general question, so I don't see a problem with the fact that I've given a more general answer. Besides which, I think the modern "computer" contexts (particularly, the centrality of *do/undo* concepts in computing), mean that "conventional" constraints on **un[verb]** don't necessarily apply there.