# What is the difference between "dewatering" and "unwatering"

Tags: differences, prefixes, gerunds, un-de

[This report](http://video.today.msnbc.msn.com/today/49638099/#49638099) on the aftermath of [Hurricane Sandy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Sandy) refers to the process of removing water as *unwatering*. However, I always thought that this process was called *dewatering*. What,  if any, is the difference between these terms?

[The dictionary does not give an entry for *unwatering*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unwatering?s=t). But a quick [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&rlz=&q=unwatering&oq=unwatering&gs_l=igoogle.3..0l2j0i10i30l2j0i30j0i10i30l2.99.1002.0.1129.6.6.0.0.0.0.136.513.4j2.6.0...0.0...1ac.1.iQmgq9of_KE) suggests the term seems to be widely used. If *unwatering* is not a valid term, why is *dewatering* not used instead?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/how-productive-is-the-prefix-un

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you? Also, note that the MSN article clearly places _unwatering_ within quotes.

Comment: Congratulations for such interesting question. My reference says: "Water control is lumped into two categories—dewatering and unwatering. Water control is the removal or control of groundwater or seepage from below the surface (dewatering) or the removal or control of ponded or flowing surface water by ditches, surface drains, or sumps (unwatering)."

Comment: @coleopterist The dictionary does not give an entry for "unwatering". But a quick google search suggests the term seems to be widely used. If "unwatering" is not a valid term, why is "dewatering" not used instead?

Comment: I have no idea. I am unfamiliar with either term. All the information in your comment is pertinent; please add it to your question along with relevant links.

Comment: @coleopterist Fair enough. I've added that now.

Comment: Both these are recent terms with arbitrary stipulated meanings (I had never heard either til the latest hurricane news). So most people won't be clear on the meaning 'has something to do with removing water?', much less the nuance/difference).

Comment: I think it's General Reference that [**un-** is both a productive and well-known 'negating prefix'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/), ***and*** that placing a "nonce-word" in quotes (as per OP's citation) is a commonplace way of indicating *this might not actually be a word, but the meaning should be obvious in context*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Corps of Engineers uses the term *unwatering* to describe removing water from locations where it is not supposed to be (subway tunnels, house basements).  *Dewatering* describes removing water from locations where it is usually located (inside locks, river beds).

Reference: http://www.capradio.org/news/npr/story?storyid=163988271

Answer (score 1):

*Dewater* is the usual verb that has the meaning *to remove water* (*from*).

By contrast, like many other such words, *unwater* more often appears in the past tense as an **adjective**, rather than by itself as a verb. An *unwatered* plant is one that has not been *watered*.

Usages such as (to) *unwater* (something) or *unwatering* something always sound odd and out of place, though not rare. Some dictionaries have defined *unwatering* as akin to *dewatering*.

Referring to the process of removing water as *unwatering* as you stated the article does, is to focus on the context: *dewatering* relates closely to the **process**, *unwatering* would draw attention to the **site** ('rendering the site better by removing water'). This is kind of a semantics-pragmatics technique. Journalese is full of such.

Comment: In the US Navy we used dewatering pumps in flooding emergencies (1st career).  In civil engineering we dewatered flooded areas by various means (2nd career).  Until today I'd never heard the term "unwater" in reference to any of these.  The only example I've ever heard was the reference to an unwatered plant as above.  Hopefully I never have to do this again in my third career (software).

Answer (score 0):

The most frequently used term for the process of removing water is [dehydration](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dehydrate).  However, as the linked definition notes, this is used for removing excess water from an object, not removing standing water.

According to [this article](http://www.impactenvironmental.com/service/water-control), the difference is that "dewatering" refers to the removal of any standing water in general, where as "unwatering" is specifically "the removal of standing rainwater in shallow contaminated excavations".

You could also refer to the specific method of removal, such as pumping.

Answer (score 0):

*[Unwatering](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwater)* means to draw off or remove water from a place by bucket or pump. On the other hand, *[dewatering](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/de/dewatering.html)* is the removal of ground water from open spaces or pores in soil or rocks.