# How to know if the beginning of a word is a true prefix

Tags: etymology, prefixes, word-formation

In English, I think it is fairly obvious when some words have a prefix. For example,

> *recall*, *return*, *remove*, *superconductor*, etc.

You can actually separate the prefix from the root word and have a root word with a different meaning.

But other words aren’t so clear like,

> *repeat*, *redundant*, etc.

Obviously the root words in these situations are in Latin or a different language, or maybe there isn’t a prefix and the word is one unit. Is there an easy way to determine if something is a prefix or not? For example, *submarine* and *substance* both start with ***sub-*** but I am inclined to think the ***sub-*** in substance is not a prefix because the meaning of ***sub-*** is under, but substance lacks that meaning.

Comment: What's your definition of a true prefix? English has various categories of prefix - there are [productive prefixes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/how-productive-is-the-verb-prefix-un), non-productive prefixes, prefixes in words taken from other languages (where if you know the language you may be able to form a new English word), prefixes which don't seem to change the meaning of words (con-), as well as compound words where the first part is a word in its own right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most dictionaries define a *prefix* as

> a letter or group of letters added to the beginning of a word to make a new word. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prefix))

So if you follow that, you can identify a prefix by removing it and seeing if you are left with a word or rather a part of a word that has no meaning in English.

EDIT: Prompted by a certain *[sigh](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1505248?noredirect=1)*, I am adding a more accurate definition of *prefix*:

> an *[affix](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affix)* attached to the beginning of a *word, base, or phrase* and serving to produce a derivative word or an inflectional form ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prefix))

In his article *Some Important Prefix Types*, Paul Fanning follows the same line:

> ***post-*** in *postpone* and *posthumous* is not a prefix because *-pone* and *-humous* are not possible words. ([guinlist](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/146-some-important-prefix-types/)).

But if you dig in the etymology of each word, you will discover that although some words may not look like they have a prefix in English, they did have one in the language in which they were born and came into English with it. Not all dictionaries provide etymology, but Etymonline is helpful in this matter.

Thus *re-* in *[repeat](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=repeat)* was a prefix in Latin (same for *[redundant](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=redundant)*):

> from from Old French ***repeter***, from ***re-*** "again" + ***petere*** "to go to; attack; strive after; ask for, beseech" (from PIE root ****pet-*** "to rush, to fly").

It is true that ****-peat*** is not an English word before which ***re-*** was stuck, the process happened way before it became an English word. So you are not wrong in thinking that it's no use dissecting the word in ***re-peat***. I personally prefer to know that the meaning of the Latin prefix ***re-*** is included in this word, because it helps me understand and assimilate it better. This is the same ***re-*** you find in *remove* and *recall*.

***Substance*** is an interesting word. The word *stance* was so fused with the prefix *sub-* that it is hard to say it contains a prefix. However, you are left with ***stance*** after removing the prefix, and ***stance*** is an English word. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=substance) says it comes:

> from ***sub*** "up to, under" + ***stare*** "to stand," from PIE root ****sta-*** "to stand, make or be firm."

*Substance* came into English as a philosophical and theological term:

> The Ancient Greek term ***ousia*** was translated in Latin as ***essentia*** or ***substantia***, and hence in English as ***essence*** or ***substance***. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ousia))

***Substantia*** was understood like something firm ***under*** your feet that helps you ***stand*** and not crumble into nothingness. This meaning was not preserved in English.

It is in the 14th century that the meaning of the word shifted to what we are more familiar with today:

> Meaning "any kind of corporeal matter" is first attested mid-14c. Sense of "the matter of a study, discourse, etc." first recorded late 14c. ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=substance))

I would argue that if you use ***substance*** in philosophical or theological contexts, you'd better be aware of the prefix ***sub-***. If you use it with its wider meaning, then the prefix is less important and may be ignored. I would personally still consider it a prefix whose meaning is obscured in modern use, but was relevant in the past.

In his dictionary *[Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings](https://www.affixes.org/alpha/s/sub-.html)*,  British etymologist and writer [Michael Quinion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Quinion) says:

> Some examples where ***sub‑*** *became attached in Latin*, and in which it has a *figurative association in English*, include ***subdue*** (*ducere*, to lead or draw); ***sublime*** (in which the second element may be related to *limen*, threshold); ***subscribe*** (*scribere*, to write); ***subjugate*** (*jugum*, yoke); ***submit*** (*mittere*, to send, put); and ***subsequent*** (*sequi*, to follow).

I would include ***substance*** in this category.

Comment: "a letter or group of letters" ... sigh

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Your comment made me smile and realise that indeed, Cambridge's dictionary is simplistic. I hope my edit will replace the sigh with a smile :)

Comment: Just flashbacks to many a dinner conversation trying to explain to people that words != letters

Comment: I found this answer to have the appropriate amount of detail. It was adequately petative and sufficiently dundat.

Comment: @R.M. You mean, _petitive_ and _dundant_?

Comment: Much appreciated!! I like the details and resources. Will definitely check them out some more.